# Using a single xcode proj for iphone and ipad- can I use same push notification certificate?

Tags: iphone, ipad, certificate

I am looking for extending my current iphone app for iPad-specific UI. For the same Apple has mentioned 3 ways, however I am using the method where a Single XCODE proj is used for having 2 targets- iphone & iPad. There are a few queries:

1. two binaries will be created , which I can price differently for selling. Will they need 2 have different certificates from Apple ?
2. My app has Push notifications. So will i require 2 different certificates ?

Answer (score 0):

Your app's will require unique AppID's to appear as separate apps in the AppStore - thus requiring separate certificates.

I guess that you would be able to install both app's on an iPad at the same time which underlines the need for two separate AppId's and distinct push notification certificates.